# How to use TopTabNavigation and BottomTabNavigation with different using?

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

For example I want to use same tabnavigation in 1 page,or just top navigation in 1 page etc.
How to use differently initialRouteName?

```
const rootTabNav = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: NavigationHome,
    Personal: NavigationPersonal,
    Info: NavigationInfo,
    News: NavigationNews,
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      // create button icons
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        return (
          <NavBottomTabIcon
            tintColor={tintColor}
            routeName={routeName as any}
            screenProps={(navigation as any).getScreenProps()}
            />
        );
      },
      title: trans('title_'+navigation.state.routeName.toLocaleLowerCase()),
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: COLORS.b,
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
  }
)
 const rootNav = createStackNavigator(
  {
    BottomTabNav: rootTabNav,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'BottomTabNav',
    headerMode: 'none',
    mode: 'modal',
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(rootNav);
```

If i add some TopTabNab and change in `initialRouteName:` all pages will have topTabNavigaton

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question?I think all you want is to have top tab at some screens and some screens without that.Right?

Comment: @AbdulBasit yes. At some screen I wan to have top tab and also bottom and some screens without top

Comment: Could you please share the screen designs for both requirements? @bekanur98

Comment: @AbdulBasit thank u. I've found solution